# How could I find the percentage of customers who made a transaction in the first 90 days of enrolling as a store member?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to find the *PERCENTAGE* of customers who have made a purchase in the first 90 days of becoming store benefit members. I've initially tried writing two separate queries and then performed my calculations from there, but I would like to have it in one query if possible (I'm still new to SQL). I want to compare this over time, so I've been including the benefits enrollment date as well.

I am using Amazon Redshift.

I've tried writing two separate queries, but I want to combine them if possible.

```
/*
* Numerator (counting customers with purchases within 90 days of becoming members)
*/
SELECT 
    c.customer_id, 
    c.member_start
FROM
     (SELECT * FROM before_2012_data
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT  * FROM after_2012_data
     ) t
     LEFT JOIN customer_information c
     ON c.customer_id = t.customer_id
WHERE DATEDIFF(day, c.member_start, t.purchase_data) between 0 and 90 
GROUP BY  member_start, c.customer_id
ORDER BY member_start

/*
* Denominator (counting customers both with and without purchases within 90 days of becoming members)
*/
SELECT 
  c.customer_id, 
  c.member_start
FROM
     (SELECT * FROM before_2012_data
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT  * FROM after_2012_data
     ) t
     LEFT JOIN customer_information c
     ON c.customer_id = t.customer_id
GROUP BY  member_start, c.customer_id
ORDER BY member_start
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hoping, I understood your question correctly. you can check below query.

```
SELECT 
    count(case when DATEDIFF(day, c.member_start, t.purchase_data) between 0 and 90  then t.customer_id end) / NULLIF(count(t.customer_id),0)
FROM
     (SELECT * FROM before_2012_data
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT  * FROM after_2012_data
     ) t
     LEFT JOIN customer_information c
     ON c.customer_id = t.customer_id;
```

Comment: I also get this error from using your version: Invalid operation: Divide by zero;

Comment: Your edit won't fix anything (if such a problem exists), because you are replacing a null count with zero; another divide by zero.

Comment: I have updated my answer, I think this is the case when total rows are zero.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Sorry, I didn't get your point, in my updated answer I used NULLIF   to solve a common `division by zero` in SQL by handling total count like `NULLIF(count(c.customer_id),0)`.

Comment: Thanks. I just tried it out, but now I get a single column with a single row containing a 0. I know there is information within the tables since I just ran ```SELECT Count(customer_id)
FROM customer_information;``` and it returned the correct number.

Comment: @dte324 Please check after joining with your union table query also. Hopefully, after join returned row count is zero.

Comment: This also produces a non-zero number. ```SELECT Count(DISTINCT t.customer_id)
FROM
     (SELECT * FROM before_2012_data
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT  * FROM after_2012_data
      ) t
     LEFT JOIN customer_information c
     ON c.customer_id = t.customer_id
;```

Comment: @dte324 In question you have made left join with `customer_information` but in the comment, you used `d_customer` table.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. I fixed that. It still produces the correct non-zero number.

Comment: Unfortunately, it still returns a single column with several rows of just 0. Thank you anyway for all of your time for looking into this.

Answer (score 0):

You may use conditional aggregation with a single query:

```
SELECT
    c.customer_id,
    c.member_start,
    100.0 * COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day, c.member_start, t.purchase_data)
                            BETWEEN 0 AND 90 THEN 1 END) / COUNT(*) AS percentage
FROM
(
    SELECT * FROM before_2012_data
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM after_2012_data
) t
LEFT JOIN customer_information c
    ON c.customer_id = t.customer_id
GROUP BY
    c.customer_id,
    c.member_start
ORDER BY
    c.member_start;
```

Comment: This results: Invalid operation: Divide by zero

Comment: I somehow doubt this, because a given group of records, by definition, has to have at least one record in it, and therefore `COUNT(*)` should never be zero in the above query.  Are you sure that you are running my exact code?

Comment: It outputs a a single column with several rows of just 0

Comment: I can't really diagnose that result set without knowing what your sample data looks like.  Of all data, how likely is it for a customer to have activity within the last 90 days?  If that's not likely, then it might explain why you see so many zeroes.

Comment: Here is some sample data from another query.    (customer id, member sign up data, first purchase after singing up, date differences)
4357309457    2014-06-25 00:00:00 2014-07-28 00:00:00 33
2349042809    2014-06-27 00:00:00 2014-07-28 00:00:00 31
2509867480    2014-04-30 00:00:00 2014-07-29 00:00:00 90